# SQL Server Management Studio Error Access Denied Editing Job Step

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms, jobs

I recently changed the owner of a job from my user to sa. After the ownership change I am able to edit the Schedules and Notifications for the job. However all attempts to to create New, Insert, Edit, or Delete job steps result in the window closing with the error 'Access Denied'.
I tried changing the owner back to my user and also granted my user the SQLAgentOperatorRole in msdb, but the 'Access Denied' error persists when changing job steps.

This error also occurs when creating a new job. It's impossible to Create a job step.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though the problem was with SQL Server, but it appears to have been caused by some bug in SSMS. Rebooting my PC solved the problem.